# make[1] Error 1 when building Library

Tags: c++, makefile

I use the following script to build a C++ Library. For i386 architecture everything works fine, but for arm64 I get an error message.

***The Error:***

```
make[1]: *** [base/low/cl_low_div.lo] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

***The Script :***

```
#!/bin/bash

PLATFORMPATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms"
TOOLSPATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.1"
pwd=`pwd`

findLatestSDKVersion()
{
sdks=`ls $PLATFORMPATH/$1.platform/Developer/SDKs`
arr=()
for sdk in $sdks
do
   arr[${#arr[@]}]=$sdk
done

# Last item will be the current SDK, since it is alpha ordered
count=${#arr[@]}
if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
   sdk=${arr[$count-1]:${#1}}
   num=`expr ${#sdk}-4`
   SDKVERSION=${sdk:0:$num}
else
   SDKVERSION="10.1"
fi
}

buildit()
{
target=$1
hosttarget=$1
platform=$2

if [[ $hosttarget == "x86_64" ]]; then
    hostarget="i386"
elif [[ $hosttarget == "arm64" ]]; then
    hosttarget="arm"
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find clang)"
export CPP="$CC -E"
export CFLAGS="-arch ${target} -isysroot $PLATFORMPATH/$platform.platform/Developer/SDKs/$platform$SDKVERSION.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVERSION"
export AR=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find ar)
export RANLIB=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find ranlib)
export CPPFLAGS="-arch ${target}  -isysroot $PLATFORMPATH/$platform.platform/Developer/SDKs/$platform$SDKVERSION.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=$SDKVERSION"
export LDFLAGS="-arch ${target} -isysroot $PLATFORMPATH/$platform.platform/Developer/SDKs/$platform$SDKVERSION.sdk"

mkdir -p $pwd/output/$target

 ./configure --prefix="$pwd/output/$target" --disable-shared --disable-sqlite --host=$hosttarget-apple-darwin

make clean
make
make install
}

findLatestSDKVersion iPhoneOS

buildit arm64 iPhoneOS

lipo -create ./output/arm64/lib/libcln.a -output libcln.a
```

One of the errors (all are similar):

```
base/low/cl_low_div.cc:210:8: error: declaration of 'divu_64_rest' in global
  scope conflicts with declaration with C language linkage
  uint64 divu_64_rest;
         ^
./base/cl_low.h:982:21: note: declared with C language linkage here
  extern "C" uint64 divu_64_rest;                         // -> Rest r
```

I could not find information on the connection between this and the architecture the library is being built for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Error 1" is a summary line, not the actual error message.

Comment: Alright, where can I find the error message then ?

Comment: Read more of what it is in your console. We cannot see it from here!

Comment: If you don't run make with `-j` (parallel) then likely it's right before the make error message.  In any event it will contain error messages that probably include the word "error" / "warning" etc., and should mention `base/low/cl_low_div` somehow since that's the target make invoked some command to build.

Answer (score 0):

Please post errors in your question, not somewhere else, especially not someplace that that doesn't allow plain text copy/paste.  Choose the relevant parts of the complete output and post that only, not the mass of useless content.

Your problem is that in the header file `cl_low.h` you declare a variable like this:

```
extern "C" uint64 divu_64_rest;
```

but in your source file `cl_low_div.cc` you define it as:

```
uint64 divu_64_rest;
```

Those are not the same.  You must have `extern "C"` (or not) identically both when you declare the variable and when you define it.  All your errors seem to be similar.

Comment: So in order to fix my problem I would prepend extern "C" to the conflicting definitions ? But why doesn't this error come up, when building for i386 ?

Comment: I suppose that for whatever reason when you compile for i386 either this code isn't used, or else there is no name mangling of this type on i386 while there is on x64.  I should point out that in your script you're finding a C compiler and setting the CC variable, but your code (at least this part of it) is written in C++, not C... you probably should also find a C++ compiler and set the CXX variable.

Comment: Alright, so the problem may be the compiler. The script is not made by me but I can't find the Question on Stackoverflow where I found it. How do I change the search of the compiler ? I only have a brief understanding of this script.

Comment: That is a different question and it's hard to provide answers in comments with little formatting.  But basically you want to add a line like `export CXX=$(xcrun -sdk iphoneos -find clang++)"`.  However, I didn't say that was your problem necessarily.  I just said that you're overriding the C compiler but your code is written in C++.  It really is incorrect for the variable declaration to have a different linkage than the variable definition.